# Flip/Mirror an Image inside a Webview on Android

Tags: android, webkit, webkit-transform

I'm looking to flip/mirror an image assigned to a DOM using the background property with CSS inside a Webview on Android with the following:

> -webkit-transform:translate3d(280px,135px,0) scale3d(-1,1,1);

Now, the problem is that it seems that Android's implementation of Webkit doesn't listen to the scale() or the scale3d() attached to the -webkit-transform property.  Having that been said, is there a way to get the image to be a mirror image of itself inside an Android Webview?

BTW, the same HTML5/JS/CSS3 code works inside Safari and iOS Simulator.  Also, translate3d() works fine, but rotate3d() fails just like scale3d().

Answer (score 0):

First, look at this : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12451.

"scale3d" only works since Android 3.0. But the android issue 12451 still exists.

Comment: I'm well aware of this bug (actually, I have a post in that thread).  What I need is a solution to flip/mirror an image.  Is there a workaround inside Android 2.x to do this?  Again, I know about limitations regarding 3d transforms inside Android 2.x Webkit, but those limitations don't remove my requirement, and I still need a workaround.  Do you have a workaround?

Comment: Sorry if I sound agitated about this, but I'm under a deadline to release a product, and there's no solution in sight.  You compound that with the fact that many on boards like this never offer solutions, but just repeat the obvious.  Don't tell me that scale3d doesn't work -- I already know that! Tell me how to get around the problem; otherwise, STFU!

Comment: Oh yeah, please don't offer as a solution to create mirrored images in Photoshop.  I've been down that road, and it's not feasible for my needs.  Again, I need a REAL workaround in JAVASCRIPT.  I'm getting frustrated by Android's wonkiness due to their wanting to do things different forces things to break.  I normally don't like Apple products, but I have to say in this instance, it just works.  Can't say that about Google.